# Statically copy C-string of variable length

Tags: c, copy, c-strings

Suppose I have the function `foo`, where I wish to create a deep copy of the contents of `input_str` and store it within the pointer `temp_cpy`. Are there any C-string functions that can do this without dynamically allocating memory to `temp_cpy`?

```
void foo(const char *input_str)
{
    char *temp_cpy = NULL;
}
```

I don't wish to simply set `temp_cpy = input_str`, as `temp_cpy` will be modified within the function, but `input_str` should remain intact.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** have storage space somewhere for the contents of your string copy. There is no magical way to make a copy of something, that doesn't require additional storage.

This however can be on the stack, as apposed to the heap, using a [variable-length array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array).

[`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) and [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) can be used to accomplish this:

```
void foo(const char *input_str)
{
    char temp[strlen(input_str) + 1];
    strcpy(temp, str);
    /* ... */
}
```

If your platform does not support VLAs, you must use heap memory. The [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup) function is usually available. If it is not, it can be replicated easily with [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). You must remember to [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) this memory when you are finished with it.

```
void foo(const char *input_str)
{
    char *temp = strdup(input_str);
    /* ... */
    free(temp);
}
```

or

```
void foo(const char *input_str)
{
    char *temp = malloc(strlen(input_str) + 1);
    strcpy(temp, input_str);
    /* ... */
    free(temp);
}
```

If your platform does not support VLAs, and you really can not use the heap for some reason, the only option left is a buffer of a predetermined maximum length. This is a special case, and should be avoided, if possible, as it creates additional limitations you must keep track of.

```
#define MAX_FOO_BUFSZ 255

void foo(const char *input_str)
{                         
    char buffer[MAX_FOO_BUFSZ + 1] = { 0 };
    strncpy(buffer, input_str, MAX_FOO_BUFSZ);    
    
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that not all compilers support VLAs (looking at you Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `strdup` function (it is POSIX but it is supported by most implementations)

```
char *foo(const char *input_str)
{
    char *temp = strdup(input_str);
    if(temp)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Remember to free the allocated memory when not needed.